# Short TypeScript import statement syntax not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to shorten the imports statements in my Angular project i.e

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/authentication.service';
```

to

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_service';
```

I am following an article where the author has used this technique and I did as he described but when I try to serve the application, I am get the error that module '@app/_service is not found in terminal i.e

```
  src/app/_helpers/jwt-interceptor.ts(6,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@app/_services'.
```

Author described to do the following changes in tsconfig.json

my **tsconfig.json** is as below.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
    "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I have tried this solution described in this video too but no luck. I am also using index.ts file to export all modules in a directory as described in [article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/08/06/angular-8-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example).

[Short Imports with TypeScript Path Mapping](https://youtu.be/1FOfL6bDSF4)

Any solution for this problem OR what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the `"baseUrl": "./"` to `"baseUrl": "src"` and also omitting @ from paths object I am able to import without any error.

```
{
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
          "es2018",
          "dom"
        ]
      },
      "paths": {
        "app/*": ["app/*"],
        "environments/*": ["environments/*"]
      },
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `index.ts` file to your `_services` folder and make the following entry.

```
export * from './authentication.service';
```

Then make sure, your import matches the `_services` folder name (you may have forgotten the trailing 's').

Comment: Try to import from 'app/_services' (omit '@')

Comment: By removing @ it has stopped to show error in editor but still there are error when I try to serve the application.

Answer (score 1):

> If the shortened path does not work, try to build the project or restart the code editor e.g. VS Code.

For usage examples, see [How to short path to file in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661754/how-to-short-path-to-file-in-angular/64297813#64297813).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the service name at least in the import.

Have a look on [this article](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/)

Comment: This link is no longer good.