# How to short path to file in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

In some CSS files I have import:

```
@import "../../../theme.scss"
@import "../../theme.scss"
@import "../../../../../../theme.scss"
@import "../theme.scss"
```

How to use relative path as absolute path everywhere for all cases:

```
@import "theme.scss"
```

My full angulr.json code is:

```
"reon-core": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/reon-core",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/reon-core/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./projects/reon-core/src/lib/tssource/"]
            },
            "tsConfig": "projects/reon-core/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/reon-core/ng-package.json"
          }
        }
```

....It returns `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).`;

Comment: May be this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42865933/11719787

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the path to the `stylePreprocessorOptions` in the `angular.json` file:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./src/assets/style/theme"
              ]
            },
         },
         "test": {
           ...
           "options": {
             ...
             "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
               "includePaths": [
                 "./src/assets/style/theme"
               ]
             }
           }
         }
}
```

Then you should be able to include your file like `@import 'app-theme.scss';`

- For more insights read this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles
- Official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

### Update after description changed

I suppose you set the wrong relative path. Your root folder should be `reon-core`. Therefore you need to set the `stylePreprocessorOptions` like that:

```
"includePaths": ["./src/lib/tssource/"]
```

in `build` and `test`

After you set this, you can put in any theme file there and like:

`./src/lib/tssource/theme.scss` and import it like `@import 'theme.scss';`

Comment: So, if file theme.scss is located not in ./src/ should I specify path to this file from angular.json?

Comment: I get the same error ` Can't find stylesheet to import.`

Comment: is it path to directory or path to file css? "includePaths": [] ?

Comment: `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).`

Comment: It must be in `/src` otherwise you have to change your source folder to bundle.

Comment: it is located outside of src. it is library Angular /projects/lib/

Comment: it does not work, I hav tried to move scss to /src/assets/themes

Comment: If it is outside of your source, it needs to be hosted somewhere. Otherwise it won't work when you later deploy it to a server or want to host it, since the build will just contain everything you bundled before and it won't have access to your localhost file system.

Comment: @OPV Other than that. Double check your config. I use this in all of my projects (also in production) like that and it worked for me.

Comment: Found it: Change `"includePaths": ["./projects/reon-core/src/lib/tssource/"]` to `"includePaths": ["./src/lib/tssource/"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can make this by adding to your tsconfig.json  {compilerOptions: {path: HERE!!} }

```
"paths": {
  "core-js/es7/reflect": ["node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"],
  "core-js/es6/*": ["node_modules/core-js/es/*"],
  "@swagger/*": ["src/app/_swagger/*"],
  "@swagger": ["src/app/_swagger/index.ts"],
  "@directives/*": ["src/app/_directives/*"],
  "@services/*": ["src/app/_services/*"],
  "@models/*": ["src/app/_models/*"],
  "@tables/*": ["src/app/tables/*"],
  "@tables_services/*": ["src/app/tables/services/*"],
  "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
  "@language/*": ["src/app/_language/*"],
  "moment": [
    "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mena this: `  "paths": {"theme": ["/path/to/theme.scss"],}`?

Comment: No you must add to tsconfig.json

Comment: Could you edit your answer according my question and my data

Comment: I have file theme.scss I need import this everywhere in styles files]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `theme.scss` is located in `src/styles/theme.scss` or `src/assets/styles/theme.scss`.

Add this path to `angular.json` **shown below**

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
     "src/styles",
     "src/assests/styles"
  ]
}
```

Now you can import it directly using path `@import 'theme.scss'`

Comment: it is located outside of src. it is library Angular /projects/lib/

Answer (score 1):

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/assets/styles",
            "src/assets/styles/theme.scss"
          ]
```

Edit for your path to style file from `src/PATH/theme.scss`
than after rebuild your project restart I mean you can use it in your style like this
@import "theme";

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

> If the shortened path does not work, try to build the project or restart the code editor e.g. VS Code.

***tsconfig.json:***

```
{
    "CompilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["app/core/*"]
            "@services/*": ["app/services/*"]
        }
    }
    # ...
}
```

***posts.component.ts:***

```
import { SeoService } from '@core/seo.service.ts';
import { PostsService } from '@services/posts.service.ts';
```