# How to use sass-loader in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

How to turn on sass-loader in Angular?

I try to use `@import "theme.scss"; inside`*.scss` files.

But I get message;

> File to import not found or unreadable: theme.scss.

I dont use webpack, only tsconfig and angular.jon

Where file **theme.scss** contains variables:

```
$border-radius: 10px;
$main: rgb(20, 100, 192);
```

Comment: are you sure the `theme.scss` file lives in the same directory as the `scss` file you're importing it in?

Comment: No this file is in root. but I need to get this file from everywhere in project

Comment: Propably I can set path rull in tsconfig or how?

Comment: try to modify the angular.json 
projects > projectName > architect > build > options > ````"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
       "includePaths": [
        "the/path"
       ]
      },```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Import `.scss` file into other `.scss` files

You can specify the `.scss` inside other `.scss` files using the relative path of your file inside the assets path.

Your default assets path should be

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
```

which is defined in the `angular.json` file.

Example:

- You have an `app.component.scss`
- Your `theme.scss` file is in `./src/assets/theme/theme.scss`

Then you would import it inside `app.component.scss` like:

```
@import '../assets/theme/theme.scss';
```

### Specify the style preprocessor option to shorten the import

If you want to shorten the path like you described, you just add the path to the `stylePreprocessorOptions` in the `angular.json` file:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./src/assets/style/theme"
              ]
            },
         },
         "test": {
           ...
           "options": {
             ...
             "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
               "includePaths": [
                 "./src/assets/style/theme"
               ]
             }
           }
         }
}
```

Then you should be able to include your file like `@import 'theme.scss';`

- For more insights read this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles
- Official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config
- Source that I used: [How to short path to file in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661754/how-to-short-path-to-file-in-angular/59662000#59662000)

### Update after description changed

I suppose you set the wrong relative path. Therefore you need to set the `stylePreprocessorOptions` like that:

```
"includePaths": ["./src/lib"]
```

in `build` and `test`

After you set this, you can put in any theme file there and like:

`./src/lib/theme.scss` and import it like `@import 'theme.scss';`

Comment: Set only for build, not for serve option?

Comment: I get the same error: `File to import not found or unreadable: theme.scss.`

Comment: `  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["projects/test-lib/src/lib/theme.scss"]
            },`

Comment: I need use only one file `theme.scss`

Comment: It should be relative from the angular.json file, not from your projects folder

Comment: Use `./src/lib` instead like you posted

Comment: A large chunk of your answer is also part of [How to short path to file in Angular?](//stackoverflow.com/a/59662000), is this perhaps a duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, but extended to the needs of the user as it was not 100% the same question. So the 2. part is copied from my previous answer